# Alternative to Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage() in android SDK?

Tags: android, sms, provider, telephony

I want to check whether my app is the default SMS app in device or not ? In the [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) they are using `Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage()`,Where `Telephony` is a part of `android.provider.Telephony` which is a part of [open source release](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg11410.html) . Here clearly mentioned that "**you should not try to use it from your applications.**" than how can I find default SMS app in device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where Telephony is a part of android.provider.Telephony which is a part of open source release .

You are not linking to an "open source release". You are linking to an email from **2008**.

> Here clearly mentioned that "you should not try to use it from your applications."

That phrase is not mentioned in the blog post. That is from an email from **2008**.

> than how can I find default SMS app in device ?

Use `Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage()`, as is mentioned in the blog post.

Comment: As you said I am using Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage() , but I am getting Telephony undefined.Which package should I import for telephony ? because as I know Telephony is a part of android.provider.Telephony which is not a part of android SDK.

Comment: I am having problem in Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(), thats why I asked this question, I am getting Telephony undefined.

Comment: @pandit: `android.provider.Telephony` is part of the Android SDK, as of API Level 19: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.html You need to set your project's build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) to API Level 19 or higher.

Comment: this methos **Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage()** requires 19 api ....so i want alternative of above method. if any exists..??

Comment: @batman I faced the same problem. What I did was just check the OS version (if version = KitKat) and not call that API. Of course I did annotate the function. Version check is the safest and best way.

Comment: This call does not work because before API 19 there are no "default sms package".